# Бывает: вводное или сказуемое?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> Разобраться с устройством базилики, которое весьма показательно, можно
>   только если повезёт, если будет открыт внутренний двор. А есть
>   отдельные счастливчики, которые вообще поднимаются по лестнице в
>   двадцать четыре ступени - той, что берёт начало за углом в конце
>   улицы. Там настоящий вход в церковь с улицы S. Martino ai Monti. **А
>   ещё бывает пускают и в крипту.**

Ну напрашивается какой-то знак!

Может,

*А ещё бывает - пускают и в крипту.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл таков: *А ещё бывает, что пускают и в крипту.* Здесь просится запятая.

> Матушка о прихожанке: «А еще бывает, прихожане достают, совсем меры не знают. [Евгения Пищикова. Пятиэтажная Россия (2007) // «Русская Жизнь», 2008]